# AWS Codepipeline Invoke option are no available

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to run an AWS Lambda on my AWS CodePipeline, the Lambda function is set up, tested and correct, however the "invoke" option does not appear in the options dropdown - showing just build, test, etc..Some guess why?

Comment: which aws region?

Comment: @YeshodhanKulkarni My CodePipeline is in sa-east-1 (São Paulo - Brazil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [AWS Regions and Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html?shortFooter=true#lambda_region) document, AWS Lambda is not available in `sa-east-1` region.

AWS Lambda is currently available only in the below regions:

[image]

This is the reason, you are unable to see the Invoke action, which only has one option: AWS Lambda.

You need to switch your pipeline to a region, which supports AWS Lambda.

Comment: Thanks for your time, @Yeshodhan Kulkarni, I will try and validate your answer.

Comment: AWS Lambda seems to be available in Sao Paulo now as per this recent blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/aws-lambda-available-in-the-south-america-sao-paulo-region